# rqt_publisher broken ('rospack' is not defined)

Tags: rqt, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I cannot use `rqt_gui` since the last update. The topic drill down is updating without any results:

[image: image description]

And when I click on refresh, I have this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_publisher/publisher_widget.py", line 103, in _update_thread_run
    for base_type_str in rosmsg.list_msgs(package, rospack=rospack):
NameError: global name 'rospack' is not defined
```

I have just re-installed everything this weekend so my settings are clean (I already had this message before the update).

Thx for the support.

PS: rospack is installed.

**EDIT1:** as requested in the comments.

```
arnaud@hercules:~$ dpkg -p ros-hydro-rqt-publisher
Package: ros-hydro-rqt-publisher
Priority: extra
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 145
Maintainer: Dorian Scholz <scholz@sim.tu-darmstadt.de>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.3.1-0raring-20131010-0322-+0000
Depends: python-rospkg, ros-hydro-qt-gui-py-common, ros-hydro-roslib, ros-hydro-rosmsg (>= 1.9.49), ros-hydro-rqt-gui, ros-hydro-rqt-gui-py, ros-hydro-rqt-py-common
Size: 21496
Description: rqt_publisher provides a GUI plugin for publishing arbitrary messages with fixed or computed field values.
Homepage: http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_publisher
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90311/rqt_publisher-broken-(%27rospack%27-is-not-defined)/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-10-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-10-13**:
Can you tell us the version you're using by like running `$ dpkg -p ros-hydro-rqt-publisher`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in version 0.3.1 of rqt_publisher. It will be fixed in the upcoming patch release. 0.3.2.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2013-10-15**:
Any idea when this patch will be delivered?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-15**:
The release has already been made and is available in shadow-fixed (http://ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html?q=rqt_publisher). Next time the repo will be synced it will be available in public. I can't give a good estimate when that will be since we wait for some other packages to clear - may be today.

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2013-10-22**:
Updated this evening and the bug is fixed.